# Dependency hell with beautifulsoup4 and lxml

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, zipapp

I have built a small utility using Python 3.8. Among other things it extracts some data from XML files using beautifulsoup4 and lxml. I use PyCharm and virtualenv for development and my utility works just fine.

In order to distribute the util to others I have a build script that copies my code to a `dist` directory and install all dependencies into that directory using `pip install -r requirements.txt -t dist`. This also works fine and I can run the code in the `dist` directory from my system interpreter (3.8, no beautifulsoup, no lxml). The dependencies can be loaded from `dist`, it appears.

It doesn't work on other machines, though. The script produces the error message

> Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Which means that beautifulsoup4 can't find lxml (same with "lxml-xml" or "xml"). The dependencies in the `dist` dir appear to be correct, though. Nothing seems to be missing. I get the same error when I package the script as a zip app using `python -m zipapp -p "python" dist`, which yields a file `dist.pyz`. It can be executed but runs into the same error message, on my own machine.

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
beautifulsoup4
jinja2
lxml
```

And this is the instantiation of the BeautifulSoup parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, features='lxml')
```

xml_data is just a string containing some valid XML that is read from a file generated by another tool.

I am out of ideas. I have lots of experience with .NET and Java but am not the greatest Python coder on the planet. It seems that I have entered the Python version of dependency hell... I really don't want to have users of the scripts invoke `pip install lxml` on their machines. I want to distribute a self-contained app with all dependencies.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

The order of the entries in requirements.txt makes no difference (as I had hoped).

I added

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
...
e = ElementMaker()
```

to the main script in order to import lxml into my script. This yields the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "dist.pyz_*main**.py", line 4, in 
> File "", line 259, in load_module
> File "dist.pyz\lrg.py", line 3, in 
> File "", line 259, in load_module
> File "dist.pyz\lxml\builder.py", line 44, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml.etree'

when run as a zip app but works fine from my IDE that uses a virtualenv.

Comment: What happens if you put lxml in front of beautiful soup in the requirements file? I don't know enough about pip to know if that matters.

Comment: Can you add an `import lxml` to the start of your python script?

Comment: @code11, Justin: Thanks for your input. I solved it by not using beautifulsoup4 and  lxml and parsing the XML data with the built-in xml.etree API. Which wasn't too hard in this case after all.

I really like BeautifulSoup for parsing XML and HTML, but if I can't get it to work reliably on Windows machines outside of a virtualenv I can't use it.

Comment: I've been fighting this on Alpine Linux for hours. Just given up and resorted to using "html.parser" instead of lxml; works for me. :)

Comment: @KimSJ: Do you parse XML or HTML? Does html.parser work well for XML?

Comment: @RobertPetermeier I'm only parsing HTML. I shouldn't comment on XML

Comment: @KimSJ Thanks anyway for your input. I really like BeautifulSoup, but distributing it with my script was just too much pain.